# Dividends reinvested in a 401k or Coverdell ESA show up on 1099-DIV?

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, 529-plan, form-1099

In the USA, I know that dividends reinvested within a 401k, IRA, 529, or Coverdell ESA are not taxable (initially).  I was surprised to see them show up on a 1099-DIV form this year from my investment company.

1) Is this right--somehow I have a 1099-DIV with a difference between box 1a and 1b, but I won't pay tax on it?

2) Is this wrong--somehow I need to contact them to get my 1099-DIV changed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is a tax-deferred account you shouldn't be getting 1099 at all unless you withdrew something from it.

Call the company and ask them why they sent it to you.